# Jdatabase: Finding part of the string which doesn't match $X string

Tags: mysql, jdatabase

I use some mysql queries to retrieve data from a Jdatabase table as **strings**.
Now I need to find the part of that string which doesn't match another string (*which actually is a sub-string of the main string*). Its a bit confusing, but the below example will make it easy to understand.

**Main String** : `23/CSE/4/2014`

**Sub-String**  : `/CSE/4/2014`

***Required Output*** : `23`

> What would be the best way according to Joomla coding standards to
>   achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string will always be separated by forward slashes and you want to get the first value, you could explode into an array like so:

```
$string = '23/CSE/4/2014';
$array = explode('/', $string);

echo $array[0]; // 23
echo $array[1]; // CSE
echo $array[2]; // 4
echo $array[3]; // 2014
```

Comment: worked like charm!

Comment: @Saibbyweb - Good good :) You could also use a Regex but I'm crap at them.

Comment: I don't think I would require RegEx :) You have answered 80% of my questions on JSE, thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't offered any details into the variability of your input strings, so we can only assume the challenges that you may be facing.

If your sub_string is always on the right side of the value that you wish to isolate, then this will do:

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UTg5u)

```
$main_string = "23/CSE/4/2014";
$sub_string = "/CSE/4/2014";
echo str_replace($sub_string, '', $main_string);
// 23
```

If the value to be isolated may exist on either side of the sub_string, then this will do the job:

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QiJss)

```
$main_string = "23/CSE/4/2014";  // or "CSE/4/2014/23"
$sub_string = "CSE/4/2014";  // notice no leading/trailing slash on this value
echo trim(str_replace($sub_string, '', $main_string), '/');  // leading/trailing slashes are trimmed
// 23
```

If the value to be isolated may be nested inside of the substring's slash delimited values, then you have a more complicated challenge to contend with and a rethink about data formatting may be in order.

Exploding your main_string and sub_string then making iterated comparisons (or an `array_diff()` call) to filter the individual values is going to be heavy-handed and/or potentially damaging.  If the desired value is the same as one of the sub_string slash-delimited values, you will lose what you are trying to find.

p.s. Since this question is tagged with `mysql` for some reason, I'll offer the MySQL equivalent of my first snippet:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/42412)

```
SELECT REPLACE('23/CSE/4/2014', '/CSE/4/2014', '')
// 23
```